# Angular 7.2 - "component is part of the declarations of 2 modules" but it is not

Tags: angular

Updating from Angular 5.2 to Angular 7.2,

I have a component that is only used **only once** in a module

but as I "ng build --prod" the project, I get this error

```
ERROR in : Type GraphComponent in C:/myproject/src/app/widgets/graph/graph.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: 

DashBoardModule in C:/myproject/src/app/pages/dashBoard/dashBoard.module.ts and 
DashBoardModule in C:/myproject/src/app/pages/dashboard/dashBoard.module.ts
```

note that **both modules are the same**

I can't put my finger on what is wrong here, this is the component I import :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,OnChanges,SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-graph',
    templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./graph.component.css'],
})
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {
...
}
```

here is how I import the component in my module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { DashBoardComponent } from './dashBoard.component';
import { DashBoardService } from './dashBoard.service';
import { DashBoardRoutingModule } from './dashBoard.routing';

import { LoadingOverlayModule } from '../../widgets/loadingOverlay/loadingOverlay.module';
import { DataTableModule } from '../../widgets/dataTable/dataTable.module';
import { ERFormModule } from '../../widgets/erform/erform.module';

import { GraphComponent } from '../../widgets/graph/graph.component';

import { PageTitleService } from '../../widgets/pageTitle/pageTitle.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DataTableModule,
        ERFormModule,
        DashBoardRoutingModule,
        LoadingOverlayModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashBoardComponent,
        GraphComponent
    ],
    providers: [DashBoardService, FormBuilder,PageTitleService],
})
export class DashBoardModule {}
```

Here is DashBoardRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './dashBoard.component';

import { AuthGuardService } from '../../auth/authGuard.service';

const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashBoard',
        component: DashBoardComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class DashBoardRoutingModule {}
```

This should be (and was) working

is there some new consideration to take when importing a component in a module ?

regards

Comment: What does `DashBoardRoutingModule` looks like ?

Comment: here you go....

Comment: You use `forChild` to declare your routing, does that mean your application is lazy loaded ?

Comment: one component is lazyloaded (at least it was, not sure anymore, the project is big)

Comment: Could you post that lazy loading strategy too please ?

Comment: I cant find the lazy loaded component...nor remember the syntax for it, so I should use forRoot instead ?

Comment: May be you have any unused or archived module in which `GraphComponent` is also declared. Because I see there are two modules `dashboard` and `dashBoard`. That is what the error says.

Comment: @user hit a global search for `loadChildren`. And no, but I think that your issue might be related to lazy loading

Comment: @AmitChigadani good finding !

Comment: 0 matches for loadChildren

Comment: if I remove the imports, and compile, something is odd with the component itself (Cannot determine the module for class GraphComponent in C:/myproject/src/app/widgets/graph/graph.component.ts! Add GraphComponent to the NgModule to fix it.)

Comment: `DashBoardModule` is not your root module can you please share your root module where you would have mentioned bootstrap component

Answer (score 0):

May be you have any unused or archived module in which `DashboardComponent` is also declared.

Because I see there are two modules `dashboard` and `dashBoard`. That is what the error says.

Answer (score 0):

DashBoardModule in C:/myproject/src/app/pages/**dashBoard**/dashBoard.module.ts and 
DashBoardModule in C:/myproject/src/app/pages/**dashboard**/dashBoard.module.ts

dashBoard and dashboard are not the same, change them to have only one version (the name of the folder)

Comment: damned I wish there was some character warning for these....I been looking for 2 days....thanks m8

Comment: Its a tough one, it was 2 hours for me in a really small app.